# Does EmberJs support publish/subscriber eventing pattern?

Tags: ember.js

I'm recently evaluating a JavaScript framework to be used for our next project. I really like Ember. But in our application, we would need an eventing mechanism from the data layer to notify the controller layer that something has changed. I know one could use obersevers in Ember, for example,:

```
person.addObserver('fullName', function() {
  // deal with the change
});
```

But I like more in Backbone.Events that you could subscribe or publish an event, specifically:

```
var object = {};

_.extend(object, Backbone.Events);

object.on("alert", function(msg) {
  alert("Triggered " + msg);
});

object.trigger("alert", "an event");
```

Anybody has an idea whether that's doable in EmberJS?

To also give you some background about my question, our application is a real-time application. So from time to time, the backend RESTful service will fire an event to the client side (JavaScript side). I would like to have a data layer which encapsulate the access to the backend RESTful service, but also keeps a cache. I hope EmberJS.Data could help me with that (that's a separate question I want to find answers). With that, I would like also the cache to be updated whenever a change happened from the backend RESTful service. Once the cache object is updated, I would like the Controller layer to be notified. This is basically why I need some eventing mechanism in JavaScript side.

Note that the reason I don't want to use the Observers is that sometimes, an event could mean I have to perform an action, i.e. load up a message, or indicate that a voice call is coming. The backbone way seems more natuarl to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Since commit [2326580](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/2326580cda4383ee732e84a28407728fe4231bfb) - which is available since **v0.9.6** - there is an `Ember.Evented` [Mixin](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/evented.js), see http://jsfiddle.net/qJqzm/.

```js
var handler = Ember.Object.create({
    otherEvent: function() {
        console.log(arguments);
    }
});

var myObject = Ember.Object.create(Ember.Evented, {
    init: function() {
        this._super();
        this.on('alert', this, 'alert');
    },
    alert: function() {
        console.log(arguments);
    }
});
myObject.on('otherEvent', handler, 'otherEvent');

myObject.fire('alert', {
    eventObject: true
});
myObject.fire('otherEvent', {
    first: true
}, {
    second: true
});​
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want a general purpose publish/subscribe hub, you can leverage trigger/on from Evented (as pangratz said) with a little syntactic sugar.  Here's what I am doing:

```js
App.Hub = Ember.Object.create({
  init: function(){
    this.set('HUB', Ember.Object.createWithMixins(Ember.Evented, {}));
  },

  publish: function(){
    var hub = this.get('HUB');
    return hub.trigger.apply(hub, arguments);
  },

  subscribe: function(){
    var hub = this.get('HUB');
    return hub.on.apply(hub, arguments);
  }
});
```

Then, to use it in your application:

```js
App.Hub.subscribe('test-started', function(name){ 
  console.log("Test " + name + " started");
});

...

App.Hub.publish('test-started', 'Biology I');
App.Hub.publish('test-started', 'Calculus');
```

Comment: How would I unsubscribe from an event using your solution?

Comment: @Parzifal, add a method "unsubscribe" similar to "subscribe" which calls http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Evented.html#method_off instead of "on". You can then use it like `App.Hub.unsubscribe('test-started')`.