# Firing custom events from ember.js backbone style

Tags: ember.js

I have an infinite scroller that adds new elements to a page as the user scrolls.  I would like to have multiple subscribers be able to bind to an event that I fire every time the new elements are added.

Is it possible for me to raise a custom event like I can in Backbone?

For example in backbone I can create an evented model like this:

```
this.vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
```

I can then bind events like this:

```
this.vent.bind('my:custom:event', this.handler);
```

And I can then fire them like this:

```
this.trigger('my:custom:event', args);
```

Can I use Ember.evented like this or is there a better way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does EmberJs support publish/subscriber eventing pattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744777/does-emberjs-support-publish-subscriber-eventing-pattern)

Answer (score 2):

If you would like Ember.js to recognize the events, you can add those events to your App definition. 
Check out [this Understanding Ember.js article](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/the-view-layer/#toc_adding-new-events), right below the list of "included" events.

Comment: I do believe the documentation you reference is talking about browser implemented events only; specifically not the custom events the questioner is talking about. The correct Ember feature area is Ember.evented , which is for arbitrary / custom events.

Comment: @Purrell I use it to define custom (non-browser specific) events. From the doc link in my answer right below the list of standard events it says "You can add additional events to the event dispatcher when you create a new application:"