# ember code location advice?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have an ember app as a preview in an iframe which is being controlled using a postMessage.

Where is the best place in ember-cli to locate the following listener/callback?

Ideally I'd like to avoid using the container lookup, it seems a little clunky/hacky?

Many Thanks,

```
    window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

    function receiveMessage(event){
       Cr2.__container__.lookup('controller:application').transitionToRouteAnimated('chapter', {main: 'slideRight'}, edition_id,chapter_order);
    }
```

Comment: Container isn't clunky/hacky it's advanced usage ^^

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying to do - running ember in an iframe - feels already hacky to me.

What you can do is have a [pubsub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18038219/829903) at the application level, and then you can do something like:

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event){
   Cr2.Hub.publish('message', edition_id, chapter_order);
 }
```